# spring logging ignores log4j2 configuration file passed as jvm argument

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j2

I am trying to pass a log4j2 xml configuration as a jvm parameter to the spring boot plugin but for some reason spring ignores it and uses its default log4j2 config file. I could confirm the environment variable is present at runtime. Below is my setup.
pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.falcon</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-sample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>-Dlog4j.configurationFile="/Users/anedumar/Work/STS/spring-boot-sample/src/test/resources/log4j2-test.xml"</jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and my log4j2-test.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="-------->%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When I debug the application, I am seeing that spring uses its own xml packaged within as below. 
[image]
How do I pass the config location as environment variable and get it to work?

Comment: Can you post your JVM command line parameters ?

Comment: @PaulNUK the JVM args are shown in the given pom.xml ... `<jvmArguments>-Dlog4j.configurationFile="/Users/anedumar/Work/STS/spring-boot-sample/src/test/resources/log4j2-test.xml"</jvmArguments>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spring boot the property for the external logging file location is logging.config as described in the manual here:

> The various logging systems can be activated by including the
>   appropriate libraries on the classpath, and further customized by
>   providing a suitable configuration file in the root of the classpath,
>   or in a location specified by the Spring Environment property
>   logging.config.